# xymatrix arrow labels for long formulas

Tags: commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

I'm trying to label an arrow in an xymatrix but because one of the formulas is quite long the label for the arrow is appearing over the second formula rather than over the arrow. What is the best way to fix this? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix{  B\ar[r]^{\delta}  &  A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus  A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A) }\]
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the label in the exact middle of the arrow by

```
\ar[r]^-{\delta}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  B\ar[r]^-{\delta} &
  A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus  A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A
}
\]

\end{document}
```

I added `cmtip` to avoid the unsightly arrow tips that are used by default.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While you're waiting for an `xy` solution, here it is with `tikzcd`, which fixes this and many other spacing issues from `xy`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
B\arrow[r,"\delta"] & A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus  A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A \oplus A
\end{tikzcd}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I might prefer a solution with xymatrix, but this solution will work if not.